# Need help in getting the correct CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I have a decent knowledge of CSS but very poor knowledge in CSS layouts. Now I need  the following layout (ignore the div sizes)

[image]

But I am getting this

[image]

Here is my HTML and css

CSS:

```
#container
{
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    width:1024px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
}
#top-left
{
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:150px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
#right{
    float:right;
    min-height: 900px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: orange;
    /*margin-top: -100px; why this is needed?*/
}
#left{
    float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:300px;
    background: blue;
}
#center
{
    float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:500px;
    background: lime;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div  id="top-left">
        This is the top left container which is at correct position
    </div>
    <div id="right" >
    </div>
    <div id="left" >
    </div>
    <div id="center" >
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cY8sr/)

Now I have the following questions

1. Why is the `div` on right side(orange) not aligned to top by default? How can I do this?
2. The two `div` (blue and lime) are being covered by the above `div` (green). Though I can correct it using `margin-top:50px`, but when I use this and the top-left(green) div increases in height, the right `div`(orange) also shifts down and runs out of the red container. So what is the correct way?
3. This one is a general question which sometimes makes me worry, is it OK to give div sizes (which we are sure will not grow in size) as fixed like `400px X 300px`?

Comment: This is a useful website for css layout: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: for `Q#3`: it's ok as long as your device has a viewport greater than 400px: what if you browse that page from a mobile device? use instead `width: 100%; max-width: 400px; ` - try to think in terms of *responsive design*

Comment: Avoid using `position` property in your css. It will make your stylings messy especially if in mobile phones You should instead use `padding` property in your css.

Comment: why don't you try a table with margin and padding?

Comment: The orange div on the right side isn't aligned to the top in the example of what you need either.

Comment: @wannaKnowItAll probably because he wants to do it right.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com is good framework for building layout fast..

Comment: @Mr Lister After thanks for your answer that makes me search and realize that you were right (+1 from me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this [**Solved Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5K6Pq/)

change your HTML like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div  id="top-left">
        This is the top left container which is at correct position
    </div>
    <div id="right" >
    </div>
    <div id="left" >
    </div>
    <div id="center" >
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container
{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    width:1024px;
    height:100%;
     min-height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
}
#top-left
{
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:150px;
    background: lightgreen;
    float:left
}
#right{
  margin-top:25px;
    float:right;
    min-height: 900px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: orange;
    /*margin-top: -100px; why this is needed?*/
}
#left{
    float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:300px;
    background: blue;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:35px;
}
#center
{
    margin-top:35px;
    position:relative;
  float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:500px;
   position:realtive;
    background: lime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your questions,

- 1) You don't have the structure broken into two "columns" which is causing that right side to not align since there is an element on top.
- 2) This is due to the use of `position: relative;` and `top: 25px;`/`left: 25px;`. When you use those styles you need to correct the top/left on elements below it. To counter act those styles you can add a margin or if they are positioned you would just add the 25px plus what ever space you wanted between them.
- 3) It is okay to give them a fixed size but there are some things to consider: Responsive web design should avoid the use of fixed sizes, if you are going to have content inside of that div, and what the layout needs should all influence your decision.

---

This is how I would go about it but you can use other methods instead of `calc` due to mobile support.

(Without `calc` you will need to set fixed heights or use `%` for the margin but will work the same!)

`HTML` Structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftSide">
        <header>

        </header>
        <div class="sideBar">

        </div>
        <div class="mainCont">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide">

    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS` for layout:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.leftSide {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background: mediumSeaGreen;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sideBar {
    width: 30%;
    height: calc(80% - 10px);
    background: brown;
    float: left;
}

.mainCont {
    width: calc(70% - 10px);
    height: calc(80% - 10px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: tan;
    float: left;
}

.rightSide {
    width: calc(30% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Finally the fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/7jZF3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to combine the answers to your questions 1 and 2:

Mixing positioning with float-based layout is generally a bad idea, these concepts don't mix well. Side effects include overlapping of divs (sometimes this is desired, often it's not) and weird position of boxes, as observed.

To avoid these problems, i'd suggest switching to pure float-usage in this case:

*Orange div* gets `float:right` (and width)
*Top green div* doesn't get anything special (maybe `height`)
*Blue div* gets `float:left` (and width)
*Middle green div* automagically fills the rest. Add `margin-left` and `-right`, if it's the longest of those three columns.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my choice to solving this:

```
#container {
    padding: 25px;
    width:1024px;
    min-height:900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
}
#top-left {
    float:left;
    width:790px;
    height:175px;
    min-height:150px;
    background: lightgreen;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    min-height: 900px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: orange;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:250px;
    background: blue;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
#center {
    float:left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width:515px;
    background: lime;
}
```

It all depends on how fluid you want the layout to be, but I removed most of your position properties (which generally don't respond well to floats) and added a few dimensions.

http://jsfiddle.net/TNbHZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better markup for this. Also, you should avoid `position`, if possible.

Here is the markup I recommend.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-left">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content-left"></div>
        <div class="content-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-right"></div>
</div>
```

Brief CSS, is here:

```
body{background:#F00}
.container{margin:0 auto; width:1024px;}

.main-left{float:left; width:800px}
.main-right{background:orange; float:right; height:620px; width:200px}

.header{background:green; height:150px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.content-left{background:blue; float:left; height:450px; width:300px}
.content-right{background:lime; float:left; height:450px; width:500px}
```

*Note: Ofcourse clearing float is necessary!*

POC on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgcq6/

Comment: Why you suggest that I should avoid `position`?Its a great tool for creating complex layouts,though its tricky.